# Flutter animate page counter text

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, text

I am trying to implement this animation:

[image: animation]

I tried `RotateAnimatedText` but I couldn't make it work, because I only want to animate if the `currentPageIndex` of my `pageView` changes. I couldn't find any way to do this.

Does anyone know how to achieve this kind of animation? Let me know if you need any more info!

Comment: https://youtu.be/2W7POjFb88g

Comment: I couldn't make it work with `AnimatedSwitchter` either..

Comment: for your particular case you need to pass a custom `transitionBuilder` - check the official docs for some demo code

Comment: i got it working with @rrttrr answer. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this package, it will help you to create counter animation/number flip animation.

`https://pub.dev/packages/animated_flip_counter`

https://pub.dev/packages/animated_flip_counter

[image]